# calling a struct member declared in a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am trying to place functions inside a `struct` which is part of a class (here named `menu`) so I can modify the struct inside of a dedicated setup cpp file (I am trying to do this so I can modify all of the functions I want in my application in a single source file instead of changing stuff in  all of my cpp files):

```
// Menu.h
class menu
{
public:
    menu();

    struct pages
    {
        void print_page_1();
        void print_page_2();
    };
};

// Setup.cpp
struct menu::pages
{
    void print_page_1()
    {
        // ...
    }
    void print_page_2()
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Then I get an error when trying to call a function within my struct:

```
int main()
{
    menu myMenu();
    myMenu.pages.print_page_1(); // error: type name is not allowed
}
```

What does this error mean and how can I avoid it?
Thank you!

Comment: You have two definitions of the `struct menu::pages` - one within the `struct menu`, and one outside it. When a `struct` or `class` type is defined more than once, both are required to be identical (specified, essentially, as an identical set of tokens) to meet the one-definition rule and in different compilation units. If the compiler sees both definitions within one compilation unit, it can identify two definitions, and diagnose.   To define member functions of `menu::pages` avoid redefining the struct - instead define the members directly (e.g. `void menu::pages::print_page_1() {}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pages` is the name of the `struct`, it's not an object. You need an object of type `pages` inside `menu`.

Otherwise, you can have `static` methods inside `pages` and call those without creating objects.

Example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/hJxNNh)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    struct P
    {
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello from P!\n";
        }
    } p; // object of P

    struct Q
    {
        static void print()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello from Q!\n";
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.p.print();

    S::Q::print();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from P!
Hello from Q!
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a pages object in menu.

```
  #include <iostream>


class menu
{
    std::string p1 = "1";
    std::string p2 = "2";
  public:

 struct pages
  {
      menu& m;
      pages(menu &m):m(m){

      }
   void print_page_1();
   void print_page_2();
  } pages;

  menu():pages(*this){
  }
};

    void menu::pages::print_page_1()
    {
     std::cout << m.p1;// ...
    }
    void menu::pages::print_page_2()
    {
      std::cout << m.p2;// ...
    }

int main() {
    menu myMenu;
    myMenu.pages.print_page_1();
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```